# PHP-EWS : How to connect to exchange with Windows Auth.(without using username/password)

Tags: php, curl, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I've a php page which I want to connect to MS Exchange through Windows authentication for sending mail.

Everything I've found is how to connect with user/password which works great but not exactly what I want. Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: exchange is pretty locked down; are you looking to use the same server for smtp?

Comment: Yes, if it's possible

Comment: Actually, I got user's logon and email through NTLM and LDAP. But can't do anything with this for EWS connection at the moment.